# How to copy the file name to text file in which the error has occurred?

Tags: powershell

I have this small code which copies the error generated in the log files to a text file, but I also want the name of file from which the error has been copied to result.txt.

```
# Path of the log files
$file = "C:\Sdemo\powershell scripts\demo folder\*.txt"

# Copies the error to the result,txt from log files.
(gc $file) -match 'Error:' > "C:\Sdemo\powershell scripts\New folder\result.txt"
```

and I also want to know that is it possible to open that file from which the error has been copied simultaneously. If yes than how can I do that?

Comment: Start with `(gc $file) -match 'Error:' | % {write-host $_.pspath -F Cyan;$_}"`; Then, you can _open_ `$_.pspath` instead `write-host` (or build an object of unique `$_.pspath` and then _open_ all…).

Comment: I tried this  (gc $file) -match 'Error:' | % {write-host $_.pspath -ForegroundColor Cyan;$_} > "C:\Suraj\powershell scripts\New folder\result.txt"               But it displays the file name on command prompt below the script pane in powershell window. I want those file name to be copied in results.txt

Comment: `(gc $file) -match 'Error:' | % {$_.pspath;$_} > "C:\Suraj\powershell scripts\New folder\result.txt"` should do the job; you could modify it e.g. as `% {$_.PSChildName + ':' + $_}` to write filename and matching content on  one line to `result.txt`

Comment: It works but it copies the file name before each error. For eg - If there are 5 error in the log file it copies those error and also the file name five times. Is there any way by which it should copy the file name only one time and then its respective error below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-3.0). It automatically adds file name and line number to the output.

```
$file = 'C:\Sdemo\powershell scripts\demo folder\*.txt'
Get-ChildItem $file |
    Select-String -Pattern 'Error:' |
    Set-Content 'C:\Sdemo\powershell scripts\New folder\result.txt'
```

If you want the filename just once above the errors from each file you could do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $file | ForEach-Object {
    $m = (Get-Content $_.FullName) -match 'Error:'
    if ($m) {
        $_.FullName, $m | Add-Content 'C:\Sdemo\powershell scripts\New folder\result.txt'
    }
}
```

However, I do not recommend the latter, because it's much easier to filter the data when each line is prefixed with the filename, and you can easily strip filename and line number from the colon-delimited text.

Comment: Hey thanks Ansgar Wiechers, the above code is working and is giving me the exact output that i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Taking all comments in consideration:

```
#Path of the log files
$file= "C:\Sdemo\powershell scripts\demo folder\*.txt"

$lastFile = [string]::Empty
#Copies the error to the result,txt from log files.
(Get-Content $file) -match 'Error:' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        if ( $_.PSPath -ne $lastFile) { $_.PSPath } # output merely on PSPath change
        $_                                          # output matching line
        $lastFile = $_.PSPath                       
    } > "C:\Sdemo\powershell scripts\New folder\result.txt"
```

Take a look at output of the following command; you can use `PSChildName` property (only file name) instead of `PSPath` (fully qualified file name):

```
(gc $file) -match 'Error:' | % {$_ | get-member -MemberType Properties; '---'}
```

Comment: Hey thanks JosefZ , it worked exactly like what i wanted.